# How to crop the largest circle out of an image (shooting target) using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-recognition

as the title states, I'm trying to crop the largest circle out of an image. I'm using OpenCV in python. To be exact, it's a shooting target, which always has the same format, but the picture of it can be taken with any mobile device and in different lighting conditions (I will include some examples lower).

I'm completely new to image recognition, so I have been trying out many different ways of doing this, but couldn't figure out a universal solution, that would work on all of my target images.

#### Why I'm trying to do this:

My assignment is to calculate score of one or multiple shots on the given target image. I have tried color segmentation to find the shots, but since the shots can be on different backgrounds, this wouldn't work properly. So now I'm trying to see the difference between the empty shooting target image and the already shot on target image. Also, I need to be able to tell, which target it was shot on (there are two target types). So I'm trying to crop out only the target from image to get rid of the background interference and then continue with the shot identifications.

#### What I have tried so far:

1) Finding the largest circle with HoughCircles. My next step would be to somehow remove the outer part of that found circle. I have played with the configuration of HoughCircles method for quite some time, but always one of the example images wasn't highlighting the most outer circle correctly or wasn't highlighting any of the circles :/.

My final configuration looked something like this:

```
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3, 3), 0)
cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 10000, param1=50, param2=100, minRadius=200, maxRadius=0)
```

It seemed like using HoughCircles wouldn't be the right way to do this, so I moved on to another possible solution I found on the internet.

2) Finding all the countours by filtering the 'black' color range in which the circles seem to be on the pictures and than finding the largest one. The problem with this solution seemed to be that sometimes the pictures had a shadow that destroyed the outer circle and therefore it seemed impossible to crop by it.

My code looked like this:

```
# black color boundaries [B, G, R]
lower = [0, 0, 0]
upper = [150, 150, 150]

# create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
lower = np.array(lower, dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array(upper, dtype="uint8")

# find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply the mask
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(mask, 40, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

if len(contours) != 0:
    # draw in blue the contours that were founded
    cv2.drawContours(output, contours, -1, 255, 3)

    # find the biggest countour (c) by the area
    c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
```

After that, I would try to draw a circle by the largest found contour (c) and crop by it. But I have already seen that the drawn circles weren't complete (probably due to some shadow on the picture) and therefore this wouldn't work anyway.

After those failures, I have tried so many solutions from other questions on here, but none would work for my problem.

#### Example images:

[Target example 1](https://i.ibb.co/1Ljfrpv/IMG-2856-HEIC.jpg)

[Target example 2](https://i.ibb.co/t3b0NQ7/IMG-8113-HEIC.jpg)

[Target to calc score 1](https://i.ibb.co/XYb3dJQ/IMG-0068-HEIC.jpg)

[Target to calc score 2](https://i.ibb.co/2MLFpHx/IMG-1457-HEIC.jpg)

#### To be completely honest with you, I'm really lost on how to go about this. I would appreciate any help, advice, anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different types of target in your samples. You may want to process them separately or ask the user for the input, what kind of target it is. Basically, you want to know how large the black part of the target, does it cover 7-10 or 4-10.

Binarize your image. Build a histogram along X and Y -- you'll find the position of the black part of your target as `(x_left, x_right, y_top, y_bottom)`. Once you know that, you can calculate the center `((top+bottom)/2, (left+right)/2)`. After that you can easily calculate the score for every pixel of the image, since you know the center, the black spot size and the number of different score areas within.

Comment: One of the wanted features of this app is for it to actually recognize the type of target the user uploaded. I will try to build a histogram and go about it that way. But as of my knowledge of histogram, maybe it would still be beneficial for it to only do the histogram of the target and not the background behind it (it can also have black color somewhere and therefore the result wouldn't be accurate). So I'm still looking for an answer about removing the image background and after that, I will have to figure out how to find the bullet hole. Thank you for the response tho. Best regards.

Comment: Could you please provide some code for getting the coordinates of the middle black part? I have tried to make a histogram, but cannot figure out how to get the coordinates (as you mentioned in your comment). I mean the (x_left, x_right, y_top, y_bottom). Thanks in advance.